# Textview on grid item click change color

Tags: android, gridview

i want to change color for textview inside a Relative Layout sample showing with GridView , i want to change color of textview which is inside relaytivelayout on grid item click at its position .

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/rel_bg"
android:layout_width="60dp"
android:layout_height="30dp"
android:background="@drawable/grid_item_bg"
android:orientation="vertical">

<TextView
    android:textColor="@drawable/state_rel"
    android:id="@+id/bTxt"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:text="ABC"
    android:textSize="18sp" />
```

as i did with relativeLayout on grid Item clicked change background, facing problem in textview how to code for textview did nto understand this kindly please help :) thanks

Comment: Please share the code for changing the RelativeLayout background

Comment: in my grid ItemOnCLickListener method
     view.setSelected(true);

and background color using for relativeLayout

<item android:drawable="@drawable/grid_item_selected" android:state_selected="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/grid_item_selected" android:state_focused="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/grid_item_released" android:state_pressed="false" />

Comment: You can set a background color programmatically for any View: `myView.setBackground(Color.RED);`

Comment: ok i know but can you help me for textview change color?

Comment: nope :/ not want to set background want to set text color....

Answer (score 0):

In the .java file, very like acitvity_main:

First you have to initialize your TextView by saying: `TextView myTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.myid);`

Than you can simply say: `myTextView.setBackGroundColor(Color.argb(x1,x2,x3,x4);`

x1 - x4 can get a value from 0 to 250. 0 is very light, 250 is very dark.

x1 = the opacity;

x2 = red;

x3 = green;

x4 = blue;

An example: `myTextView.setBackgroundColor(Color.argb(250,250,0,0);`
would set a very red Background.

Comment: you did not understand..... this layout design is in gridview using adapter... if i did same like you said than it changes for all